# What's the difference between `overflow` properties `overlay` and `scroll`

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

What's the difference between `overflow` properties `overlay` and `scroll`.
Both adding scrollbar to overflowing content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scroll will always show scroll bars irrespective of if the content is being clipped or not.

Overlay was a webkit proprietary property but is now depreciated. It does the same thing that auto does. Which is display a scroll bar when necessary.

Just as a side note the current possible values for overflow are

```
auto
hidden
scroll
visible
```

Great article here by css tricks documenting the difference.
https://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

Comment: The same as auto isn't accurate. The scrollbar overlays as opposed to taking up space.

Answer (score 4):

Quote from [quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/overflow.html)

> **scroll:** always show horizontal and vertical scrollbars, regardless of whether they're necessary. This value is never used; you generally want auto.
>
> **overlay:** non-standard value only supported by the WebKit-browsers that does the same as auto.